# System.TypeLoadException with multiple projects in solution

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008

I have created a VS2008 solution with 3 projects in it (Class Library, Windows Application, and Web Application).  I am using objects that I define in the Class Library in both the Windows application and the web application.  This works great for the Windows application, but when I go to create an object in the code behind of a web page, I get a System.TypeLoadException:

Could not load type 'Nutz.MusicMaster.Song' from assembly 'Nutz, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Nutz.MusicMaster.Song' from assembly 'Nutz, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

I added the class library to the references in both the windows app and the web app (Right click on References -> Add Reference -> Projects).

Any ideas on what is causing this would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!
Nutzy

Comment: Does the Class Library dll exist in the bin folder of the website?

Comment: It's possible you could find results by examining the Fusion log:
http://blogs.msdn.com/suzcook/archive/2003/05/29/57120.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by creating a new solution and adding all of my existing classes, pages, and controls to it.